# Finding direct translations for foreign words in English

Tags: language-comparison

Is there any tool or method of searching for the direct translations of foreign words that have made their way into English?  Google translate and other translation services will translate the meaning and hide the direct translation.

"Cul-de-sac" is probably the best example.  Google (Fr > En) translates it to "dead end".  Often Google translate will just give back the original word like "souvenir" which it translates to "souvenir".

Comment: In terms of terminology: your example of "cul-de-sac" for example, is a word we use in American English for sure (not sure about other areas that speak English), and we usually say it just like that: for example, "I live on a cul-de-sac." is a sentence that would be very common to say in American English. Anyway, in terms of terminology, I would consider this is a 'loanword' or a 'borrowed word' from French, not really a direct translation. A direct translation might be if someone were to say "I live on a bottom-of-the-sack" but I've never heard anyone refer to a street in this way in English.

Comment: Also Google Translate is not really a good source. You have to consider the contex. You'll get better results if you input more context, but even then it's not certain and the actual words used depend on context, on region, etc. In the southern U.S., for example, we would normally prefer "cul-de-sac" in the context of telling someone where you live or where you are located. But in the context of driving directions, we would prefer "dead end" instead. This is a general problem with automatic translation -- the context is not clear, so an appropriate translation is difficult.

Comment: This phenomenon is also called 'imported words'. So searching for these may help: borrowed words, imported words, loan words, loanwords, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently discovered ChatGPT can do this by asking for the literal translation for a word. For example:

> Q: What does "cul-de-sac" literally mean in French
>
> A: "Cul-de-sac" is a French term that literally means "bottom of the bag." It is made up of two words: "cul," which means "bottom" or "backside," and "de-sac," which means "bag" or "sac." Together, these words describe a street or road that is blocked off at one end and has no through traffic, typically ending in a turnaround. The term "cul-de-sac" is used to describe a street that is a dead end.

https://chat.openai.com

Comment: The ChatGPT-generated content is [banned on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/974789) and is widely [discouraged network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/187133)

Comment: Those meta posts discourage/ban ChatGPT-written answers, not answering questions in which "ChatGPT" is the/an answer.  As demonstrated in the answer, it is a "tool or method of searching for the direct translations of foreign words".

Comment: In "cul-de-sac", the "de-sac" really means "of-bag". The "de" is a connector, not related to the bag.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388308/178179 shows that ChatGPT is useful for language learning questions. SO is just 1 of 185 Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the etymology. E.g., on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cul+de+sac+etyomology) and YouChat:

[image]

Or [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/):

> Question: What's the etymology of cul-de-sac?
>
> Answer by ChatGPT:
>
> The term "cul-de-sac" originates from French and literally translates to "bottom of the bag" or "dead-end." The word "cul" means "bottom" or "end," while "sac" means "bag" or "sack." The term was first used in the 18th century to describe a street or a passage that is closed at one end, forming a dead-end or a looped shape.
>
> The concept of a cul-de-sac can be traced back even further to ancient urban planning practices. In Roman times, the term "claudus" was used to describe a street or an alley that was closed at one end. The concept was later adopted and expanded upon by medieval European cities.
>
> Cul-de-sacs were often designed to provide a sense of security, privacy, and limited traffic flow within residential neighborhoods. Their dead-end nature meant that they provided quieter and safer living environments with less through-traffic. This design feature has been favored by some urban planners as it reduces the number of vehicles passing through, creating a more pedestrian-friendly and community-oriented space.
>
> Today, the term "cul-de-sac" is commonly used in English-speaking countries to refer to a street or a residential development with a dead-end or looped configuration.